"Send USSD failed" keeps coming up every minute
I have a Samsung Galaxy A52. The "Send USSD failed" error message keeps coming up every minute. The phone is connected to the TruConnect network.
I did all the basics, but TruConnect says it's not them.
Are there any prompts I can do?

Perhaps you need to reset it and troubleshoot from there.

Exact duplicate of Why do "send USSD failed" notifications keep popping up? (Samsung on TruConnect network). Please try the answers from there and let us know the result.

This question is similar to: Why do "send USSD failed" notifications keep popping up?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
